# YouTube API v3 search by channel Id not returning all videos in the channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

See this YouTube channel:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqiwZNUf9z9OrseJoVGWMMg

It contains 8 videos. However, the request below only returns 5 videos (even with maxResults set to 10.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?safeSearch=none&order=title&part=snippet&channelId=UCqiwZNUf9z9OrseJoVGWMMg&type=video&maxResults=10&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You can see in the first part of the JSON response that `totalResults` is only 5, not the expected 8.

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/MhPawf_XoAn1dq-tgkkE4aPpbD0\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 5,
  "resultsPerPage": 10
 },
...
```

The items array in the response only contains 5 items. I have tried many variations of the query (including turning off safeSearch) and yet it will not return all the videos in the channel.

Comment: I sometimes have different results also when searching by channelId and ordering on date. I know e.g. that for a channel there are video's for the current week, but doing the same search a minute later only gives results that are at least a week old. Very strange and not easy to replicate.

Answer (score 1):

The following request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=title&part=snippet&channelId=UCqiwZNUf9z9OrseJoVGWMMg&type=video&maxResults=10&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

yielded me the following result:

```
 {
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/8i-meJV39_yfRucbNqwGwygIReU\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 8,
  "resultsPerPage": 10
 }
```

As much as I can tell it's the same as what you have posted the only difference I tried it without safesearch parameter specified but as you can see in the item list returned - it gave back all the videos for me on the channel. I'm not sure about why the API bugged on you but it should give the proper results. Hope I may've been some help though.

PS.: Tried it with safesearch parameter as well. I got your results ( 5 videos ) with "strict" and "none" values but it gave me back all the 8 videos you've been looking for with the "moderate" value which I assume for default as it's the same I got without the parameter specified.

```
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/DlNXovOlstICaTGq9kp43GR9eBU\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "pcorjQxfwoA"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-04-08T16:59:38.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCqiwZNUf9z9OrseJoVGWMMg",
    "title": "EBB Retrofit Animation",
    "description": "This animation shows what is involved in completing a seismic retrofit on a house with a raised foundation and a 4 foot cripple wall.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pcorjQxfwoA/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pcorjQxfwoA/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pcorjQxfwoA/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/0KLoeBTh2PYOW5CwXmq4Yzxhc-8\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "RV1IzHmSojI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-04-08T17:00:17.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCqiwZNUf9z9OrseJoVGWMMg",
    "title": "EBB Retrofit HD",
    "description": "Watch Earthquake Brace + Bolt in action.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RV1IzHmSojI/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RV1IzHmSojI/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RV1IzHmSojI/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/x74SevHlVYKeMKmn3O9Toaa33Lg\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "stpSa2rIbS8"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-04-08T17:33:29.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCqiwZNUf9z9OrseJoVGWMMg",
    "title": "FEMA Training Part 2",
    "description": "This video introduces the effect of earthquakes on houses, discusses past performance of houses in earthquakes, and introduces partial seismic rehabilitation...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/stpSa2rIbS8/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/stpSa2rIbS8/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/stpSa2rIbS8/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/7sTYIalNOCQ6jn9X4VBCMphFzbk\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "jYll7dENSOo"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-04-08T17:23:02.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCqiwZNUf9z9OrseJoVGWMMg",
    "title": "FEMA Training Part 6",
    "description": "This video provides a brief overview of important concepts for identifying the load path in a structure, construction of shear walls, and correctly installin...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jYll7dENSOo/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jYll7dENSOo/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jYll7dENSOo/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/GyHVsiWjC3smdvRyhqM7k9TSAL4\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "KHNx0SluNBA"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-04-08T17:16:18.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCqiwZNUf9z9OrseJoVGWMMg",
    "title": "FEMA Training Part 4",
    "description": "This video clarifies that seismic rehabilitation work falls under the purview of the building code and building department, and gives a brief overview of code ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KHNx0SluNBA/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KHNx0SluNBA/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KHNx0SluNBA/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/qJoVONxqCG32ExIyXSOYwxgT4Q4\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "iaS1wIIrXbA"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-04-08T17:07:42.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCqiwZNUf9z9OrseJoVGWMMg",
    "title": "FEMA Training Part 1",
    "description": "This video introduces the training course, defines applicable terminology, and shows pictorially why seismic rehabilitation of houses is important.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iaS1wIIrXbA/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iaS1wIIrXbA/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iaS1wIIrXbA/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/Ps3HC7X95sTlZ-sR3ZP3lHYhQSM\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "0hQpBJJofcs"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-04-08T17:31:56.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCqiwZNUf9z9OrseJoVGWMMg",
    "title": "FEMA Training Part 5",
    "description": "This video addresses application of prescriptive provisions for anchorage to foundation and cripple wall bracing contained in the International Existing Building ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0hQpBJJofcs/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0hQpBJJofcs/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0hQpBJJofcs/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/F1VbW4J8TYbRDZuDeotUfWoBi9M\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "OLclXnCQD2k"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-04-08T17:12:49.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCqiwZNUf9z9OrseJoVGWMMg",
    "title": "FEMA Training Part 3",
    "description": "This video is the heart of the training course, introducing seismic vulnerabilities 'A through K' discussing how to identify vulnerable conditions, likely ea...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OLclXnCQD2k/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OLclXnCQD2k/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OLclXnCQD2k/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Strange. I used your exact same query and still got only 5 results. I'd say that perhaps they have cached the results for my API key or something. Thanks for taking a look at it!